Database design for dashboard (statistics of performance)
I have a device (printer) that I can connect to using protocol and query for different statistics. To keep it simple, I get in return jobname and number of total prints for that job.
Example:
    >> REQUEST jobname, printcount
 
    << mysamplejob,  39328

I can connect at will to the printer, but a "resolution" of every 10-30 seconds would be plenty. Maybe even less.
What would a meaningfull database schema look like, if I want to extract statistics per time (example: hour) - and how would I handle the fact that I only get incrementing numbers. I can not get a number from that day only.
This is first time working with historical data series, so first steps taken.
